# Is there a quick way to determine whether a class is a specialisation of a particular template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Given:

```
template <typename T1>
struct Foo {};
```

and:

```
template <typename T2>
void bar(const T2&) {}
```

I'd like to add a static assertion into `bar` to ensure that it will only work when `T2` is `Foo<T1>`.

I realise that I could do it like this:

```
template <typename T1>
void bar(const Foo<T1>&) {}
```

However, in reality `Foo`'s template parameter list is a little longer, and even if just for "logic" reasons I'd really prefer to avoid writing it out again where `bar` is defined.

How easy would it be to create a trait for this?

```
template <typename T2>
void bar(const T2&)
{
   static_assert(is_specialisation_of_v<Foo, T2>, "Only valid for kinds of Foo!");
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to spell a definition for such a trait.

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    bar(f);      // OK

    char c;
    bar(c);      // Should assert
}
```

I suppose the common school of thought is that the resulting error should come from incompatible use within `bar` itself, but I prefer more explicit constraints.

Comment: [An attempt](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58ee373fae165cea)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - [A fixed attempt](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7568d4aaedf42f8e). Pattern matching FTW.

Comment: Ah, Potatoswatter's answer there is what I need :)